# How to create anonymous error pipes of complex commands for diff?

Tags: bash, diff, output, pipe

In bash, when one needs to know the differences between two commands it is possible to use `diff` as follows:

```
diff <(foo) <(bar)
```

When `foo` and `bar` are complex commands, say `ls | grep something`

But this compares only the standard output, is there a similar command to compare the error output? Or better yet, both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When foo/bar are complex commands (e.g. with pipes/redirection):

```
diff <((foo) 2>&1) <((bar) 2>&1)
```

Explanation: `(foo)` executes `foo` in a sub shell, allowing `2>&1` to correctly merge the standard and error output into the standard output.

Executing `foo` without the sub shell will make `2>&1` merge the outputs of only the last command.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe stderr to stdout:

```
diff <(foo 2>&1) <(bar 2>&1)
```